# PayPal Subscription API integration. When do I need to create a Product?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I have to manage the recurring payment for our online service, but there is an aspect not very clear to me.
From what I understand, to manage a subscription I need to:

1. Create the product
2. Create the subscription plan
3. Create the subscription
   I have done some tests and everything works correctly.
   What I don't understand is whether the product and the respective subscription plan need to be created for each transaction or if I first need to create a product list with their associated subscription plans and always use the same items when creating the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `product` and `subscription plan` for the first time. If any person has subscribed to your product, the money will be automatically deducted at the onset of the next billing cycle. It will use the same product and plan for which the person has subscribed for.

For more detail, you can go through https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/paypal-subscription-in-react-1121c39b26be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I want to offer a service whose cost depends on the type of subscription (standard, professional, business) and number of users (1 to 4, 5 to 10, over 10), do I have to create 9 different products?
Standard 1 to 4 / Standard 5 to 10 / Standard over 10 / Professional 1 to 4....
Is it correct?

Comment: There are two types of pricing offered by PayPal Subscription(Fixed/Quantity). You can use quantity pricing if the price varies with the number of products bought or else go for fixed pricing where the price is fixed.

In your use case, you need to create 9 different types of products.

Answer (score 1):

Create new Products and Plans when you have new Products, or are offering new or additional Plans.

Otherwise, use existing items for new Subscriptions.